# Shall I revert back to ERB from HAML?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, haml, erb

I recently requested a project based on Rails and engaged a freelancer for the job. Basically backend was good but on the frontside - was advised by the freelancer to convert all HTML to Haml and Sass.

It was difficult -as it was hard to find another expert to convert these. In the end manage to find a guy for it

However now i needed updates to the webpage and I realized most people use the Erb and Css instead. Can Erb work together with Haml? Go back to Css as well?

Using  Bootstrap as framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERB can work with Haml, just don't mix them in the same file. You can use .scss file extension instead of .sass: SCSS is superset of CSS, i.e. any valid CSS is valid SCSS.

Comment: Thank you! It is helpful

Comment: On StackOverflow it is common to thank by accepting the answer :)